# Variance of function types wrt. interfaces

Tags: f#, generic-variance

I'm trying to understand the variance rules for function types. It seems they don't treat input and output the same (up to duality). Consider this program.

```
let mk1 s = s |> Seq.iter (fun _ -> ())
//  val mk1 : s:seq<'a> -> unit
let mk2 = mk1 : list<int> -> unit        // Ok. 

let mk3 () = [1] 
// val mk3 : unit -> int list
let mk4 = mk3 : unit -> seq<int>      // Type mismatch.
```

This is the error:

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    unit -> seq<int>    
but given a
    unit -> int list    
The type 'seq<int>' does not match the type 'int list'
```

It's my understanding that `seq<int>` is an interface type, one which `int list` implements, so I was expecting this cast to go through(*).

Two questions:

1. Why doesn't it?
2. Why is the cast producing `mk2` ok?

---

(*) For theorists: I was expecting the elaborator to exhibit dual behaviour on the input and output positions of the function space type constructor. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You have this:

```
let mk4 = mk3  : unit -> seq<int>
```

Which will not compile, the up-cast will happen automatically in the input parameter but never in the output of the function. This is in the [spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html), section 14.4.2 Implicit Insertion of Flexibility for Uses of Functions and Members.

*This means that F# functions whose inferred type includes an unsealed type in argument position may be passed subtypes when called, without the need for explicit upcasts.*

This makes possible to define another version of the function which is restricted to a subtype, which are the other cases you're showing.

Comment: Argh. I typed it in wrongly. I updated the question, to ask what I actually want. (I hope.)

Comment: Ok, thanks, very helpful. I took the liberty of removing your answers to my mistyped original question from your answer.

Comment: That's fine, it will reduce the noise !

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, you can use flexible types to define `mk4` as follows:

```
let mk4 = mk3 : unit -> #seq<int>
```

It compiles but automatically lifts the type of `mk4` up to `unit -> int list`

Comment: Yes, cause the Type Inference is smart enough to figure out the only subtype of seq that will return is list. It's a typical case when the type annotation is more generic than the one inferred, a warning is displayed in these cases.